# Why is Final Render not like Viewport Render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

Final render of my grass is nothing like the viewport render. In the final render it is showing much less grass than the viewport render.

I'd like to know if this is okay or something is wrong.

[image: Final Rendered Image]

[image: Viewport Rendered Image]

Comment: It's probably creating particle systems to distribute the foliage, which will have viewport and render settings for number of children, for instance.

Comment: so it is okay and I should not be worried about it?